# Hibernate and Date Type: length attribute

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I would like to understand what the attribute `length = 7` refers to a field of type Date:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "EVENT_DATE", length = 7)
public Date getEventDate() {
    return this.eventDate;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the javadocs its irrelevant in that case:

> (Optional) The column length. (Applies only if a string-valued column
>   is used.)